# Consider the integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

So I missed class today and decided to take a look at the homework assigned. This notation is unfamiliar to me. Up until this point, we have just been finding over and underestimates based on Riemann sums, given an interval and n.  Could someone walk me through this; both the interpretation of the problem and one of the questions.

Comment: This is unacceptable behavior for this site. It is inappropriate to ask questions to others for the sole reason of being too lazy or unwilling to do your own work.

Comment: @mixedmath you're ridiculous. I missed a class for reasons I certainly don't need to justify to anyone on the internet, and I've asked for help in interpreting a notation I've never seen before. If I'm not mistaken, that's precisely the sort of thing this site is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to perform Riemann sums on the interval $[a,b]$ with $n$ divisions.   One of these may be familiar to you.   The other two might have been introduced in the lesson you skipped.

Take: $\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n}, x_k=a+k\Delta x, k\in\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$

$$\begin{align}
\text{Using the left endpoint of the intervals:}\qquad & S_\text{left} = \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_{k-1})\Delta x
\\
\text{Using the right end point of the interval:}\qquad & S_\text{right} = \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k)\Delta x
\\
\text{Using the mid point of each interval:}\qquad & S_\text{mid} = \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_{k-1}+\tfrac {\Delta x}2)\Delta x 
\end{align}$$

Can you do your homework now?  All you're being asked is to find the Riemann sum of $f(x)= \frac 2 x + 2$ over the interval $[5,9]$ for $n=4$ divisions using the left and right endpoint methods.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, take a look here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum

Then take a look at your textbook. I've found they're actually much better and the instructor usually takes problems from them word-for-word in many cases (annoying many times because I usually do chapters ahead of time). In this particular case, every instructor I've ever had has taken problems from the book and in any example, if you can't figure it out, simply type in "riemann sum of ___" or something of the sort into Google. This is a classic topic for Calc I and Calc II courses (when it came up again in Calc II I was *so* disappointed...).

Just remember that you're *approximating* the area of a region using rectangles, and the area of a rectangle is just about the most basic formula there is. Then realize that some of the sides repeat, and you can thus simplify the formula. If you know any programming write a quick program (almost any language will do) that will let you test the rather tedious hand-work to make sure you're right. There are many ways to approximate numerically, including using trapezoids, rectangles and even parabolas (Simpson's method, and by far IMHO the best).

By the way...as per your comment about textbooks, many times it's because you're not *really* paying attention to what they're saying in the book or spending enough time. Glancing does not help with math -- you must really spend time, like hours.

Comment: To the OP: Maths makes our brains work a bit hard. It's not like reading literature. To read mathematics takes even more effort than for example read Nietzsche or Kant (who are quite difficult to read). You need to have fighting spirit to advance in maths.

Comment: @VladimirVargas I certainly agree! (+1)